# Amazon ads integration not working

Tags: android, ads, amazon-appstore

I'm testing the Amazon Ads for the first time and i'm following Amazon Quick Start Guide Its the sample project which is given in the sdk

But still i'm getting these errors- **Logcat**

```
01-16 12:37:11.359: E/AmazonMobileAds SISGenerateDIDRequest WebRequest HttpURLConnectionWebRequest(6212): Problem while creating output steam for request body: aax-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
01-16 12:37:11.359: E/AmazonMobileAds AdRequest WebRequest HttpURLConnectionWebRequest(6212): Problem while creating output steam for request body: aax-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
01-16 12:37:11.359: E/AmazonMobileAds AdLoader(6212): Could not contact Ad Server
01-16 12:37:11.367: W/SimpleAdSample(6212): Ad failed to load. Code: NETWORK_ERROR, Message: Could not contact Ad Server
```

Here is the Layout.XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:Amazon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.amazon.device.ads"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">

 <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="bottom|center">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/load_ad_button"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:text="@string/button_text"
         android:textSize="8.5pt">
     </Button>

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textSize="6.5pt"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:text="@string/description">
     </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download last AdSDK version https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk

Comment: I downloaded it last night from the same link.

Comment: Following Event Tracking and Errors

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/event-tracking-and-errors

NETWORK_ERROR The ad request failed due to problems with network connectivity. Try again when a connection becomes available.

Comment: I'm on the wifi and posting comments from the same .

Comment: So, try later, maybe Amazon Ad Server really not available now